# Select item, and select name of parent

Tags: mysql

Quickie:

Table structure:

```
id | name | parent_id
```

I want to run a query for ID's, but also return that item's parent_id and the name of that id as well.

To better explain

```
SELECT id, name FROM sections
```

...then for each ID, return the ID and name of its parent using the "parent_id" column.

I'm trying to get this into an array:

```
[0]
    [id]
    [name]
    [parent_id]
    [parent_name]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT s.id, s.name, s.parent_id, p.name as parent_name
FROM sections s LEFT JOIN sections p ON s.parent_id = p.id
```

Basically you just want to join the table against itself and bring in the name field as the parent name.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, b.id as parent_id, b.name as parent_name
FROM sections a
INNER JOIN sections b on a.parent_id = b.id
```

(could also do an outer join if there are nodes without parents)

Answer (score 1):

just join the table to itself

something like:

SELECT child.id, child.name, child.parent_id, parent.name AS parentname
FROM tablename child LEFT JOIN tablename parent ON child.parent_id = parent.id

Answer (score 1):

is doing a join more effective than simply doing subselects?

```
select id as childID , name as childName, parent_id as pid, (select id from sections where id = pid) as parentID, (select name from sections where id = pid) as parentName from sections;
```

the bigger issue is that this is non recursive... I'm curious how one would go about getting this to grow ad infinitum for relationships that are multi-generational.

Comment: In this instance, the join should be faster (especially on large result sets). You are right though, you can't easily find a grand parent/child with this type of scheme. For that you either need recursion, or you could look into nested sets (Google: sql nested set model)

Comment: Another option would be to store the path to the child node in sql instead of just the parent id (eg /1/3/10 where 10 is the id of the parent, 1 is the id of the great-grand parent)

Answer (score 0):

You can have many solutions like ::

1 >

```
Select id as id, name as id_name, (Select id from sections where id=parent_id) as parent_id, (Select name from sections where id=parent_id) as parent_name 
from sections where .....
```

2 >

```
Select child.id, child.name, parent.id, parent.name 
 from sections child
 inner join sections parent on (parent.id=child.parent_id)
 where .....
```

You can implement any one, but i prefer the 2nd one..